Application of Brenier Theorem
Brenier Theorem says that, if the cost function is quadratic and the probability measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $L$, then there exists a unique gradient of a convex function $u$ such that $T=\nabla u$ solves the Monge problem from $\mu$ to $\nu$.
My question is: this theorem gives me an existence result but it does not really help me in explicitly determining $T$ since I don't know the expression for $u$. For example, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^2$ and $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[2,3]^2$, how can I explicitly recover an expression for $T$?
